# Openlayers map not displaying until map div clicked, and then at wrong position

Tags: cordova, openlayers, openstreetmap

I'm trying to place an OpenLayers OSM map in an App using PhoneGap and JQuery Mobile, but the map won't display in the Xcode iOS simulator until I click on the area or a control. I've read the related questions and implemented a "DeviceReady" check, but it's not making any difference.

What's more, when I do get the map to appear, it comes up at close to max extent rather than zoomed-in. I've added to alerts to the code, and am finding that while alert 1 fires correctly, alert 2 doesn't fire. However if I replace the .setCenter and .zoom instructions with a .zoomToMaxExtent, it does (though the map still doesn't load without clicking). Can anyone help?

Giles

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
<title>My Page</title> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobilecus-1.1.0.min.css"/>
        <script src="cordova-1.8.1.js"></script>
        <script src="js/OpenLayers.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/sessionstorage.1.4.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

        var map

        function init() {
            map = new OpenLayers.Map("mapholder", {maxResolution:300});
            map.addLayer(new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM());
            var lonlat = new OpenLayers.LonLat( -0.1279688 ,51.5077286 )
            .transform(
                       new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), // transform from WGS 1984
                       map.getProjectionObject() // to Spherical Mercator Projection
                       );
            var zoom=16;
            alert ("1!");
            //map.zoomToMaxExtent; //alert 2 fires if I uncomment this and comment 
// the 2 lines below
            map.setCenter (lonlat);
            map.zoom (zoom);
            alert ("2!"); // doesn't fire with setCenter and zoom lines active, and 
// map  doesn't center or zoom either.
        }


    $(function() { //ready

    <!-- JQUERY STUFF TRIMMED -->

    }); //end ready

        function onBodyLoad(){
            document.addEventListener("deviceready",init(),false);
        }

   </script>

</head>

<body onload="onBodyLoad();"> 
<div data-role="page" id="page1" class="page">
    <!-- page 1 stuff here -->
</div><!-- /page -->

<div data-role="page" id="page2" class="page">
    <div data-role="header" data-id="fixedheader" data-position="fixed" >   
    <h1>Fixed header</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">
    <div id="leftbar">
      <img src="images/leftbar.png">
    </div><!-- /leftbar -->
    <div id="mapview">
        <div id = "mapholder">
        <!-- map should load here -->
        </div>
    </div><!-- /mapview -->
    </div><!-- /content -->

    <div data-role="footer"data-id="fixedfooter" data-position="fixed">
    <a id="ForwardButton">Forward</a><a id = "BackButton" href="#page2">Back</a>
    </div><!--/footer -->
</div><!-- /page -->

</body>
</html>
```

---

Okay I tried rebuilding my file from scratch, starting from a simple map view and adding back the other page components. Seems like it's not an OpenLayers issue, but something to do with page or div loading - my app layout has two separate pages in the same html file, with the map on the second page, and that seems to be causing the problem. Swapping the map for the content on the first page (so the map is the first thing you see when the html loads), it works fine - but the jQuery script acting on divs on the second page is now not working! Now I've clarified the issue I'll look for a solution and if necessary post a more tightly defined question...

Answer (score 1):

change your function

```
  function onBodyLoad(){
      init();
      document.addEventListener("deviceready",init(),false);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Yogesh - I've changed the function as you marked, but it doesn't seem to make any difference to either of the problems I'm having! One piece of additional info - when I do get the map to load by clicking, it does seem to be centring on the right coordinates - but it's not applying any kind of zoom... Thanks, Giles

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem before and found a solution that works, but it feels a bit hacky. The problem is that for some reason OpenLayers makes tiles invisible, so the solution would be to make them visible when map loads:

```
$(document).delegate("#map-page", "pageshow", function() {
    $(".olLayerDiv").children("div").not(":visible").show();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion igorti - I tried it out just in case but I don't think I'm having the same problem... As I said in my answer above, it looks like I have a more general issue with recognising events on the "second" page, whatever it is. Probably something obvious I'm missing (I'm new to all this!) but I'm going to try a couple of experiments to narrow it down... :-)

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready",init(),false);
```

Calls init() immediately, rather than passing a reference to the function to be called when the event is dispatched.

As it is, init is being called in the onload handler, not as the device ready handler, which is what you want.

Try this instead:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready",init,false);
```